# Why does Oracle's JDBC driver not support Oracle's Boolean type

Tags: java, oracle, exception, jdbc, boolean

I am new to JDBC and have been playing with it. Other posts in the forum indicate that Oracle's JDBC driver does not support Oracle PLSQL Boolean type. I find that really strange:

From the [oracle jdbc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28925) it seems like it does:

[image]

But in [another section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#JJDBC28981) it says it does not allow passing of BOOLEAN parameters to PL/SQL stored procedures.

Isn't the the documentation contradicting itself ?

It does not let me pass or accept Boolean values from PL/SQL procedures/functions. It gives me the following exception:

```
Exception occured in the database
Exception message: Invalid column type: 16
Database error code: 17004
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 16
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:3963)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:135)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:304)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:393)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1579)
    at com.HrManager.insertNewEmployee(HrManager.java:1300)
    at com.HrManager.main(HrManager.java:1411)
```

I am trying to understand why JDBC Oracle Drivers do not support Boolean types. Is it because PL/SQL `"Boolean"` accepts null values and Java's primitive type `"boolean"` does not ?

But the counter to it would be , Java's wrapper class `"Boolean"` does accept nulls. This can be used to map to PLSQL's Boolean type . Can some one throw more light on this.

Comment: [There's precedent to suggest](http://its-all-about-oracle.blogspot.com/2013/11/invalid-column-type-16.html) that you're getting an integer back instead of a boolean, but show us what you've written to get this error.

Comment: If it's a case as mentioned by @Makato change the value of the property "hibernate.dialect" from "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" to "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"

Answer (score 5):

From: [PL/SQL TABLE, BOOLEAN, and RECORD Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#BABFECBJ)

> It is not feasible for Oracle JDBC drivers to support calling arguments or return values of the PL/SQL RECORD, BOOLEAN, or table with non-scalar element types. However, Oracle JDBC drivers support PL/SQL index-by table of scalar element types.
>
> ...
>
> As a workaround to PL/SQL RECORD, BOOLEAN, or non-scalar table types, create container procedures that handle the data as types supported by JDBC. For example, to wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL boolean, create a stored procedure that takes a character or number from JDBC and passes it to the original procedure as BOOLEAN or, for an output parameter, accepts a BOOLEAN argument from the original procedure and passes it as a CHAR or NUMBER to JDBC. Similarly, to wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL records, create a stored procedure that handles a record in its individual components, such as CHAR and NUMBER, or in a structured object type. To wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL tables, break the data into components or perhaps use Oracle collection types.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error while using Boolean in an entity. 
Resolved it by changing oracle dialect to 'org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect' from 'org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect'.

Answer (score 0):

As answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55413745/4612499 (with code examples) the Oracle JDBC thin driver supports the PLSQL BOOLEAN type starting in 12.2.

Answer (score -1):

Java supports null values for primitive values using the `wasNull` method on `ResultSet` and `CallableStatement`, so that is no reason for not supporting `BOOLEAN`.

However the documentation you link to says it is [not supported](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#BABFECBJ). You may be able to use [oracle specific extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraint.htm#BABCJFDA). The documentation also links to [an example workaround](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#i1005380) (for parameter passing, but the analogue for OUT is easy to deduce).