# Error calling an Oracle function from Java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to call an Oracle function using Java, and I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCION'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCION'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This is the way I am using to call that function:

```
String ejecucion = "{ ?=call function(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }";

CallableStatement cons = c.ejecutarProcedimiento(ejecucion, 0);  // Here I invoke "prepareCall" method
double monto = 0;

cons.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.FLOAT);

// Parametro del procedimiento almacenado
cons.setFloat(2, 2);
cons.setDouble(3, importe);
cons.setDate(4,TareasGenerales.convertirFecha(Parametros.cabezal.getFechaVencimientoPresentacion()));                                                                                 
 cons.setDate(5,TareasGenerales.convertirFecha(Parametros.cabezal.getFechaVencmientoPago()));
cons.setDate(6, TareasGenerales.convertirFecha(Parametros.fechaActual));
cons.setDate(7, TareasGenerales.convertirFecha(Parametros.fechaActual));
cons.setBoolean(8, false);
cons.setInt(9, Integer.valueOf(Parametros.cabezal.getAnioMesDesde()));
cons.setBoolean(10, false);

cons.executeQuery();
```

When I execute the last line, I get the error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

```
 declare
 -- Boolean parameters are translated from/to integers: 
 -- 0/1/null <--> false/true/null 
  pa_a boolean := sys.diutil.int_to_bool(:a);
  pa_b boolean := sys.diutil.int_to_bool(:b);
begin
  -- Call the function
  :result := function(c=> :c,
                                           d => :d,
                                           e => :e,
                                           f => :f,
                                           g => :g,
                                           h => :g,
                                           i => i,
                                           j => :j,
                                           k => k);
end;
```

I added Oracle function definition.

Upload 2.0:

```
FUNCTION Prueba(tipo_calc           IN NUMBER,
                        impte           IN NUMBER,
                        f_venc         IN DATE,
                        f_venc_p         DATE,
                        f_pre          IN DATE,
                        f_pa            IN DATE,
                        pa_tiene IN BOOLEAN,
                        pa_anio         IN NUMBER,
                        pa_buen     IN BOOLEAN) RETURN NUMBER;
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the definition of `function` as well.

Comment: What happened to argument #5?  I see 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, but no 5.

Comment: Enabled result Float 
Enabled a Float 
Enabled b Float 
Enabled c Date 
Enabled d Date 
Enabled f Date 
Enabled g Date 
Enabled h Integer 
Enabled i Float 
Enabled j Integer

Comment: @duffymo,I made a mistake when I wrote the previous code. If you look at it again, you'll notice I included the fifth parameter, then it's not the reason of the error.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Comment: how many parameters does the function take in? It could also be that the parameters may start at 0 instead of 1 (not sure though)

Comment: JDBC starts at 1.  I still don't see 5, even though I refreshed.  Voting to close.

Comment: @duffymo, check it again, I edited my message.

Comment: Show us the Oracle function definition, otherwise how can we help identify the mismatch between what the Java code is doing and the Oracle function? --- And did you really create a function named `function` (as named in Java code) or `FUNCION` (as named in error message)? And which is it: `function` or `FUNCION`?

Comment: maybe one of your parameters has the wrong type associated with it?

Comment: @Andreas, I added the Oracle function definition. Refresh the question.

Comment: @Andreas, the real name is not "function", but I chose it because I can't show certain information in a public place.

Comment: @RickGrimes 1) The *name* of the function is proprietary? Really? The name alone all out of context? Wow! --- 2) That is not the function *definition*. That is some unrelated PL/SQL code *calling* the function. Show the definition of the function. You don't have to include the function body, we just need to see the definition of parameters and return value.

Comment: @Andreas, it's ready.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but Oracle SQL doesn't have a `BOOLEAN` datatype, only PL/SQL does. This means that the method can only be called by other PL/SQL code, and cannot be called directly by SQL, e.g. you cannot call the function from a `SELECT` statement. Oracle JDBC is SQL, not PL/SQL. You need to create another function to wrap the function and convert a `NUMBER` datatype, like the PL/SQL code block you showed does.

Comment: Related: [Why does JDBC not support Oracle boolean type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132648/why-does-jdbc-not-support-oracle-boolean-type)

Comment: @Andraes, thank you for your answer. Can you show me an example? I don't know how to implement the solution you suggested.

Comment: So is your Java code calling the function as you originally showed (in which case you can't just pass zero to a boolean formal parameter anyway); or is it executing the anonymous block, but with different bind placeholders? It's unclear what you are really doing.

Comment: @AlexPoole, that's what I'm really doing. I just changed int values to boolean and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to create a wrapper function in PL SQL that has `NUMBER` instead of `BOOLEAN` as the type of those two parameters. The function would call this one, converting 0->false etc.

Comment: @MickMnemonic, I understand, but I changed types to boolean in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCION'

Check how many params have the function in the database.

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't work. You can check how many params we used in a previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem, passing my arguments directly in String "ejecucion" instead of adding them after.