# Executing PL/SQL functions and procedures from Java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

So I have the following PL/SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertUser (nume VARCHAR2, parola VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN IS    
    existaNume INTEGER;
    succes boolean;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into existaNume from utilizatori where utilizatori.username = nume;
    IF (existaNume >= 1)
    THEN
        succes:=false;
        RETURN succes;
    ELSE
        insert into utilizatori values(nume, parola, 0, 'online');
        succes:=true;
        return succes;
    END IF;
END;
```

that I call from Java using the following code:

```
public boolean insertUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        boolean temp = false;
        CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call insertUser (?, ?)}");
        cstmt.setString(2, username);
        cstmt.setString(3, password);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter (1, OracleTypes.BOOLEAN);
        cstmt.executeUpdate();
        return cstmt.getBoolean(1);
    }
```

But the problem is that I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 16
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:4469)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:159)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:345)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:537)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1307)
    at PLSQL.insertUser(PLSQL.java:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: this could be of help -- http://its-all-about-oracle.blogspot.com/2013/11/invalid-column-type-16.html

Comment: You might be able to [use PLSQL_BOOLEAN instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55413745/266304), depending on your driver/DB version.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public Boolean insertUser(String nume, String parola) throws Exception {

    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withSchemaName("SCHEMA_NAME")
            .withCatalogName("PACKAGE_NAME")
            .withFunctionName("FUNCTION_NAME");
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("NUME", nume)
            .addValue("PAROLA", parola);
    return caller.executeFunction(Boolean.class, in);
}
```